# Copy between two different AWS S3 accounts

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using the C# library for AWS.
We have a scenario where a 3rd party has granted us read access to their S3 bucket. Is it possible to copy objects from their S3 bucket into one of ours without doing a round trip (i.e. GET and PUT)?

I found this in the AWS documentation:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html

but that seems to apply only to their REST API, not to the C# library I am using

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what bwight seems to think, it just doesn't work that way. The only way to get this to work without an necessary round-trip is to use the exact same credentials to access BOTH buckets. So the only way to get it to work is to have the owner of the source bucket (in my case its a 3rd party) to grant access to one of your user accounts to list/read from their bucket. They just need to modify their bucket policy to include something like this:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/someusername"
}
```

and then grant whatever permissions needed to it in the policy

Comment: Nothing I said was incorrect. I said the method in C# would work if your permissions were set correctly. I quote, "I see no reason why not if the permissions are set correctly."

Answer (score 0):

The same method is available for the C# SDK. I'm not sure if you can copy to buckets across accounts but I see no reason why not if the permissions are set correctly. If this doesn't work I'd say it's not possible.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/?topic=html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Client_CopyObject.htm

Comment: That is the CopyObject method, that's not what I am asking about. I am asking about the "PUT Object - Copy" method which seems only to be available via their REST API for some reason

Comment: This is the same method just named differently. The SDK Documentation notes "The CopyObjectRequest contains the parameters used for the CopyObject operation. For more information about the optional parameters, refer: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/RESTObjectCOPY.html"

Comment: That's your answer? To provide me with the same link I posted in my initial question? I think you are confused and/or mistaken

Comment: You say, "but that seems to apply only to their REST API, not to the C# library I am using". I'm telling you that in the documentation for the C# library you're using the documentation says that the C# method CopyObject calls the RESTObjectCOPY REST API.

Comment: you're just not getting it...you don't think that was the first thing I tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that any language you use to work with AWS services, such as S3, will under the hood communicate with that service's API.  The question is if SDK has support for the underlying method, in this case the PUT-copy one.

If you are doing this across accounts the IAM user/key pair you are using must have READ access to the source object and WRITE access to the destination bucket.